# Git stash local or in git repository

Tags: git, repository, git-stash

Someone created a git stash on my computer and I would like to know, if he also has git and can change to the branch, if he can download the stash or is the stash local on my computer?

Answer (score 2):

At first, it is local, but you can create a branch in order to share it:

```
git branch new_branch stash@{0}
```

If you then publish/copy `new_branch`, the other person can get it and start working on the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Stashes are local, and I would recommend only using them to temporarily stash (i know, right?) your changes, say to work around conflicts while switchen between branches. For anything else, git branches are your friend. Even more so if you want to share the work in it with someone else.